# Struts 1.3.10 in embedded Jetty. ActionServlet can't find /WEB-INF/web.xml

Tags: java, struts, jetty, embed

**The state:**

- I have a Struts 1.3 based webapp that deploys just fine to Tomcat (war or exploded).
- I combine the webapp with a class to run embedded jetty 7.x. This all goes into a single jar file.
- I use maven-assembly-plugin to package all dependencies exploded into the single jar. I looked inside the jar file and all is as you would expect. Standard web app layout except all dependent classes are in a standard package layout. WEB-INF/web.xml right where you would expect it.
- Jetty launches fine and runs my first startup servlet that does some database initialization. My JspConfiguration uses the path "WEB-INF/web.xml" to get the web.xml (note missing leading slash).

**The problem**

- When the Struts action servlet initializes, it specifically makes the following call:

  InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/web.xml");

which results in:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: The /WEB-INF/web.xml was not found.
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initServlet(ActionServlet.java:1781)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:260)
```

**The question:**

I imagine it's due to struts using the leading slash when requesting the resource.

- Should I package differently?
- Should I have code that captures that request and tweaks the URI to remove the leading slash? How?
- I'd rather not tweak the struts code if possible....
- If you decide to help, thanks!

**The info:**

Here is the class I'm using to fire up jetty along with the two dependent classes.

```
public class JettyRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args == null) {
            args = new String[0];
        }


        // Construct the new arguments for jetty-runner
        boolean transientState = false;


        int port = 8070;

        Server server = new Server(port);

        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext(".", "");
        webapp.setConfigurations(new Configuration[]{new JspConfiguration()});


        ClassPathResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ClassPathResourceHandler();
        resourceHandler.setContextPath("");

        ContextHandlerCollection contexts = new ContextHandlerCollection();

        contexts.addHandler(resourceHandler);
        contexts.addHandler(webapp);

        server.setHandler(contexts);
        //server.setHandler(webapp);
        URL jettyXmlURL = new JettyRunner().getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("jetty.xml");
        XmlConfiguration configuration = new XmlConfiguration(jettyXmlURL); //or use new XmlConfiguration(new FileInputStream("myJetty.xml"));
        //XmlConfiguration configuration = new XmlConfiguration(new FileInputStream("jetty.xml"));
        configuration.configure(server);

        server.start();
        server.join();

    }


}

public class JspConfiguration extends WebXmlConfiguration {

    @Override
    public Resource findWebXml(WebAppContext webAppContext) throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
        URL path = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("WEB-INF/web.xml");
        return  Resource.newResource(path);
    }
}

public class ClassPathResourceHandler extends ContextHandler {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(startupServlet.class.getName());

    private ResourceHandler realResourceHandler = null;

    public ClassPathResourceHandler() {
        realResourceHandler = new ResourceHandlerImplementation();
    }

    @Override
    public void doHandle(String s, Request request, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException, ServletException {
        realResourceHandler.handle(s, request, httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }

    private class ResourceHandlerImplementation extends ResourceHandler {

        @Override
        protected Resource getResource(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) throws MalformedURLException {

            String requestedFile = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
            log.debug("getResource(): " + requestedFile);

            URL path = getClass().getResource(requestedFile);

            try {
                Resource resource = Resource.newResource(path);
                if (resource != null && resource.exists() && !resource.isDirectory()) {
                    return resource;
                }
                else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Struts was designed to run as a Web application and not as a standalone application. In your `JettyRunner` class, you have a `main` method to fire up Jetty. That won't work with Struts. You would have to create a web application if you want to use Struts 1.x.

Comment: thanks for your response. It _is_ a web app that runs just fine in tomcat/resin/weblogic and standalone jetty. The issue is with Struts' ActionServlet finding the WEB-INF/web.xml while running in an _embedded_ jetty server. The web app launches, just the servlet init fails finding this resource.

I may have not been clear in the way I asked my question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this for my struts 1.3 app using WebAppContext's `setWar()` method. My version of a basic jetty runner looks like:

```
public class JettyRunner {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JettyRunner.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
        context.setWar(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/webapp/");
        context.setContextPath("/");
        logger.debug(context.dump());

        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(context);

        server.start();
        server.join();

    }
}
```